# What is the best way to compare 2 characters ignoring case in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, char

I am making password validation method using console app and got stuck with comparing two chars. Is there a way to compare two chars without using **toUpper()** or **toLower(**)  method. 
For example if i am comparing these two chars

```
 char c1 = 'a', c2 = 'A';

        bool result = c1.Equals(c2);
```

I want result to be  **true**.

I've tried using **toLower()** method but i have a problem.

This is my password validation Method.

```
  private static bool PasswordValidation(string input)
    {        
        if(!(input.Length>=8&&input.Length<=15))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("min 8 characters max 15");
            return false;
        }

        int specialCharacters = 0, uppLatter = 0, lowerLatter = 0;
        char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
        {
            char ch = charArray[i];
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("can't use space in password");
                return false;
            }

            if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch))              
                specialCharacters++;

            if (char.IsUpper(ch))
                uppLatter++;

            if (char.IsLower(ch))
                lowerLatter++;

            if (i < charArray.Length - 1)
            {

                if (char.ToLower(charArray[i])==char.ToLower(charArray[++i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("same characters");
                    return false;
                }

                if(char.IsDigit(charArray[i])&&char.IsDigit(charArray[++i]))
                {
                    int sum = Convert.ToInt32(charArray[i]) + Convert.ToInt32(charArray[++i]);
                    if(sum==input.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("sum is equal to length");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        if (specialCharacters == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("at lesast one special character is required");
            return false;
        }
        if (uppLatter == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("at lesast one upper latter is required");
            return false;
        }
        if (lowerLatter == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("at lesast one lower character is required");
            return false;
        }


        var repeats = input.GroupBy(s1 => s1)
            .Where(s1 => s1.Count() > 3)
            .Select(s1 => s1).ToArray();

        if (repeats.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("one character can't be repeted more than 3 times");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see i've used integers to count the number of lower and upper letters, as well as special characters but this will only work for the first character of **input** string. 
Soon as i hit this

if (char.ToLower(charArray[i])==char.ToLower(charArray[++i]))

line of code, all hell breaks loose.

**Any suggestion is helpful.
Thank you for your time.**

Comment: You always incerement `i` if the condition is true or not `if (char.ToLower(charArray[i])==char.ToLower(charArray[++i]))` Change your logic and don't increment the loop index in the loop body (*BTW: Do you mean `i+1`*)

Comment: @L.B tank you for your answer but it would not change much because i am using toLower() function before incrementation. Maybe i should put else statment and decrement i (i--).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all hell breaks loose." In general it is better to describe behavior than summarize with a vague conclusion. Do you mean your loop iterates improperly? Maybe you should use `char.ToLower(charArray[i])==char.ToLower(charArray[i+1])` (with appropriate boundary checking).

Comment: Offtopic: never enforce users to follow these creepy password rules. Why do you limit the password length to 15? Why do you want to see special characters? I use passwords of 16 character length with only lowercase letters and digits which are much more stronger than typical 8-char passwords.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov this is the test my colleague had for job application that i wanted to use for practice ,so these are the requirements, but thank you for your advice :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
char c1 = 'a', c2 = 'A';

bool result = String.Equals(c1.ToString(), c2.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you , this works . I've used here if(String.Equals(charArray[i].ToString(),charArray[i+1].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))